# how to find accurately the closest species to my plant species?

Tags: evolution, bioinformatics, botany

I'm working on some bioinformatic analysis of a non-model woody plant within the family with least information. So, I'm looking for a closest species to my plant. Any suggestion would be highly appreciated. Also, It will be great if I have know about the divergence time (? million year) between two species. Is there any documents or website to address this issue? Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what data you have. What species is this?  Do you have its entire genome? Specific genes? Are there any sequences for this species or no sequences at all?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the species name, you can search [TreeBase](http://treebase.org/treebase-web/search/treeSearch.html) to find previously published phylogenetic trees which will point you towards close relatives to your species. Depending on how obscure your taxon is, though, you might not find much.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could get some information from the Angiosperm Phylogeny Group:
http://www.mobot.org/MOBOT/research/APweb/

They even have a tree where model organisms are highlighted:
http://www.mobot.org/MOBOT/research/APweb/trees/modeltreemap.html

Answer (score 1):

You can try http://timetree.org/ to get the divergence time if you already have the names of the taxa.